# How to add another parameter to my existing Specflow test?

Tags: c#, specflow

I currently have a working test which authenticates both authorized and forbidden API responses (401 and 403 responses).

I now want to add in a success parameter to the existing test rather than having to create another separate test. But I'm not sure how I would incorporate this. So essentially I would add response code as success (200) to the examples, but I'm not sure what I would set my headerCondition as. Also, to get a success (200) in my code I need to pass key 'token-auth' and value 'ToBeProvided'. I need to include this within my When step as pasted below.

```
Scenario Outline: Authenticating endpoint
When I request transaction notification endpoint with headers 
<HeaderCondition>
Then I get a response <ResponseCode>
Examples:
| ResponseCode | HeaderCondition |
| Unauthorized | false           |
| Forbidden    | true            |

[When(@"I request notification endpoint with headers (.*)")]
      public void 
WhenIRequestNotificationEndpointWithHeaders(string headerCondition)
    {
        var baseurl = "(My end point)";
        var client = new RestClient(baseurl);
        var request = new RestRequest(Method.PUT);

        if (headerCondition.Equals("true"))
        {
            request.AddHeader("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", "b601454182cf47eba7ahfjuejdksiwhfjmd");
            request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
            //request.AddJsonBody("{\"Id\":\"123\"}");
            request.AddParameter("undefined", "{\"Id\":\"123\"}", ParameterType.RequestBody);
        }

        response = client.Execute(request);
    }
```

Comment: Why are you reluctant to write this up as a separate test? A sure sign that you're trying to make one test do too much is when you find yourself having trouble actually writing it -- keep in mind that the resulting test, even when it works, will be none too clear to readers and maintainers either! You can reuse/generalize code to your heart's content in the actual implementation of the tests if they only differ by a flag, by packing up the whole thing as a new method, but the specification itself should focus on being readable and clearly separating different scenarios.

Comment: The parts of your test that essentially are the parameters can be written as `Given` clauses (`Given that token-auth is provided`, or if necessary, `Given that token-auth is <value>`, but make sure to set up `<value>` in the context in that case). You're not required to stuff everything into the `When` because that corresponds to "performing the request" -- the test scenario is not constrained to mirroring the timing details of the execution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either add a new boolean parameter for the When step or change the boolean you already have (technically, you have made it a string) to a string representing an enum.

Example with one more boolean (`IsSendingToken`):

```
Scenario Outline: Authenticating endpoint
When I request transaction notification endpoint with headers <HeaderCondition> and sending token <IsSendingToken>
Then I get a response <ResponseCode>

Examples:
| ResponseCode | HeaderCondition | IsSendingToken |
| Unauthorized | false           | false          |
| Forbidden    | true            | false          |
| Ok           | true            | true           |

[When(@"I request notification endpoint with headers (.*) and sending token (true|false)")]
public void WhenIRequestNotificationEndpointWithHeaders(string headerCondition, bool isSendingToken)
    {
        var baseurl = "(My end point)";
        var client = new RestClient(baseurl);
        var request = new RestRequest(Method.PUT);

        if (headerCondition.Equals("true"))
        {
            request.AddHeader("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", "b601454182cf47eba7ahfjuejdksiwhfjmd");
            request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
            //request.AddJsonBody("{\"Id\":\"123\"}");
            request.AddParameter("undefined", "{\"Id\":\"123\"}", ParameterType.RequestBody);
        }

        if (isSendingToken == true)
        {
            request.AddHeader("token-auth", "ToBeProvided");
        }

        response = client.Execute(request);
    }
```

Example with changing HeaderCondition to an enumeration (as string):

```
Scenario Outline: Authenticating endpoint
When I request transaction notification endpoint with headers <HeaderCondition>
Then I get a response <ResponseCode>

Examples:
| ResponseCode | HeaderCondition |
| Unauthorized | Unauthorized    |
| Forbidden    | Forbidden       |
| Ok           | Ok              |

[When(@"I request notification endpoint with headers (.*)")]
public void WhenIRequestNotificationEndpointWithHeaders(string headerCondition)
    {
        var baseurl = "(My end point)";
        var client = new RestClient(baseurl);
        var request = new RestRequest(Method.PUT);

        if (headerCondition.Equals("Forbidden"))
        {
            request.AddHeader("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", "b601454182cf47eba7ahfjuejdksiwhfjmd");
            request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
            //request.AddJsonBody("{\"Id\":\"123\"}");
            request.AddParameter("undefined", "{\"Id\":\"123\"}", ParameterType.RequestBody);
        }
        else if(headerCondition.Equals("Ok"))
        {
            request.AddHeader("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", "b601454182cf47eba7ahfjuejdksiwhfjmd");
            request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
            //request.AddJsonBody("{\"Id\":\"123\"}");
            request.AddParameter("undefined", "{\"Id\":\"123\"}", ParameterType.RequestBody);
            request.AddHeader("token-auth", "ToBeProvided");
        }

        response = client.Execute(request);
    }
```

I reused the ResponseCode values for the HeaderCondition. HeaderCondition could be whatever you like, as long as they match in the feature file and steps file. You could also use ResponseCode as input to the When step instead of headerCondition.